# Cannot locate json connection file created by ipython kernel

Tags: ipython, anaconda

I'm using ipython 4.1.2 (installed via Anaconda). I locate the profile location (which is the default)

```
ipython locate profile
/home/myname/.ipython/profile_default
```

`ipython kernel` runs fine, saying

> To connect another client to this kernel, use:
>       --existing kernel-8664.json

However, when I look inside `/home/myname/.ipython/profile_default/security`, it is entirely empty.

What's the issue here?

Comment: Connection files now live in a different location - run `jupyter --runtime-dir` to see where on your system.

Comment: Perfect! [The doc](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/Cookbook:-Connecting-to-a-remote-kernel-via-ssh) is wrong then. I've proposed an edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Connection files now live in a different location, because they are a component of the Jupyter architecture, rather than an IPython specific thing. The exact location depends on your system, but you can find it by running:

```
jupyter --runtime-dir
```

Or in Python code, call:

```
jupyter_core.paths.jupyter_runtime_dir()
```